# How do I re-root a eclipse project to a parent folder without break it?

Tags: eclipse, git, directory

I did a project with eclipse and I shared it on github. After much work, I realized that the whole project is in a folder called 'projectname'.

A graphic explains it better.

```
|-- README.md
`-- projectname
    |-- model
    |-- public
    |   |-- images
    |   |-- css
    |   `-- index.html
    |-- package.json
    `-- app.js
```

But I need it in the base directory.

```
|-- README.md
|-- model
|-- public
|   |-- images
|   |-- css
|   `-- index.html
|-- package.json
`-- app.js
```

So how do I move these files without breaking the repository or break the eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the project from inside of Eclipse, making sure to NOT remove the underlying files, fix the git repository, and then re-import the project from the `Git Repositories` view into the workspace.